# How to get fast data transmission from Pi 4 to Pi Pico via USB

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to establish a 'fast' data transmission from a PI 4 to a Pi Pico. According to the specs, the USB controller of the Pico should be able to go up to 12 Mbit/s.

### Approach #1

My currently used code is to slow. The code sets the GPIO Pin 2 to high, if we receive a byte and to low after 2048 bytes received or in case of a timeout:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

const uint8_t DEBUG_PIN = 2;

int main() {

    stdio_usb_init();

    uint16_t numBytesReceived = 0; 
    int currentChar = PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

    gpio_init(DEBUG_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(DEBUG_PIN, GPIO_OUT);

    while (true) 
    {
         currentChar = getchar_timeout_us(50000);        
         if (currentChar != PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
             gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, 1);
             numBytesReceived++;

             if (2048 == numBytesReceived) {
                 gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, 0);
                 numBytesReceived = 0;                
             }
         }
         else {
             gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, 0);         
             numBytesReceived = 0;
        
         }
     }
  }
```

On my Pi 4, I test with the code

```
import serial
import time
serialPort = "/dev/ttyACM0"

ser = serial.Serial(
    port=serialPort
)
while True:
    data_array = bytearray(2048)
    ser.write(data_array)
    ser.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Measured with an oscilloscope, the transmission time is between 24ms and 29ms. In the best case I have a throughput of

2048 * 8 / 0.024ms = 680 kBit/s,

which is to far away from the target of 12 Mbit/s.

### Approach #2

Using the pico-example [dev_lowlevel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/usb/device/dev_lowlevel). I commented out all *printf()* calls and  modified the *main()* and *ep1_out_handler()* for measurement purposes like this:

```
int main(void) {
    stdio_init_all();
    //printf("USB Device Low-Level hardware example\n");
    usb_device_init();

    gpio_init(DEBUG_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(DEBUG_PIN, GPIO_OUT);
    g_debug_state = 0;
    gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, g_debug_state);
    g_debug_state = 1;


    // Wait until configured
    while (!configured) {
        tight_loop_contents();
    }

    // Get ready to rx from host
    usb_start_transfer(usb_get_endpoint_configuration(EP1_OUT_ADDR), NULL, 64);

    // Everything is interrupt driven so just loop here
    while (1) {
        tight_loop_contents();
    }
}

void ep1_out_handler(uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len) {
    gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, g_debug_state);
    g_debug_state = ! g_debug_state;

    struct usb_endpoint_configuration *ep = usb_get_endpoint_configuration(EP2_IN_ADDR);
    usb_start_transfer(ep, NULL, 0);
}
```

On Host side, I modified the *dev_lowlevel_loopback.py* like this:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import time
# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0000, idProduct=0x0001)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

# get an endpoint instance
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0, 0)]

outep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match= \
        lambda e: \
            usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
            usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)

inep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first IN endpoint
    custom_match= \
        lambda e: \
            usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
            usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN)

assert inep is not None
assert outep is not None


test_string = bytearray(64)
while True:
    for _ in range(32):
        outep.write(test_string)
        inep.read(0)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Here, the transmission time varies between 16ms and 19ms giving a throughput of:

2048 * 8 / 0.016ms = 1024 kBit/s - still to slow.

I might loose some time by calling *inep.read(0)* after each write, but leaving this out gives an

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/pi/repositories/pico-examples/usb/device/dev_lowlevel/dev_lowlevel_loopback.py",
> line 56, in 
> outep.write(test_string)
>
> [...]
>
> usb.core.USBTimeoutError: [Errno 110] Operation timed out

on the next write.

In the function *usb_start_transfer(...)* we can find the comment

```
void usb_start_transfer(struct usb_endpoint_configuration *ep, uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len) {
    // We are asserting that the length is <= 64 bytes for simplicity of the example.
    // For multi packet transfers see THE tinyusb port.
```

I tried to find THE tinyusb port but got lost in all the tinyusb examples for the Pico.

### Approach #3

I tried to use [usb-test](https://github.com/notro/pico-usbtest). I modified *static bool usbtest_xfer_cb(...)* for measurement and debug purposes like this:

```
static bool usbtest_xfer_cb(uint8_t rhport, uint8_t ep_addr, xfer_result_t result, uint32_t xferred_bytes)
{
    USBTEST_LOG1("%s: ep_addr=0x%02x result=%u xferred_bytes=%u\n", __func__, ep_addr, result, xferred_bytes);

    board_led_activity();

    TU_VERIFY(result == XFER_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    if (!xferred_bytes)
        USBTEST_LOG2("                 ZLP\n");

    if (ep_addr == _bulk_out) {        
        TU_ASSERT ( usbd_edpt_xfer(rhport, _bulk_out, _bulk_out_buf, sizeof(_bulk_out_buf)) );
        board_led_on();
        gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, g_debug_state);
        g_debug_state = !g_debug_state;
        
    }
    else if (ep_addr == _bulk_in) {
        TU_ASSERT ( usbd_edpt_xfer(rhport, _bulk_in, _bulk_in_buf, sizeof(_bulk_in_buf)) );
        //gpio_put(DEBUG_PIN, g_debug_state);
        //g_debug_state = !g_debug_state;
    }
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

In *test.py* I enabled only test number 27 which is marked as "bulk write". Calling the script like

```
sudo python test.py -t -d
```

gives the output

> #27 iterations=1 length=512 vary=256 sglen=1 :: 0.616 ms - 811.7 kB/s
> dmesg: usbtest 1-1.3:1.0: TEST 27: bulk write 0Mbytes

According to the output, some data should have been sent. But neither the LED turns on (see code above) nor the oscilloscope shows any movement on GPIO-2. Looks like it is not working at all.

### The Question

How to get fast data transmission from Pi 4 to Pi Pico via USB?